# Verify that string array contains a certain string

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm aware that this topic has already been covered a few times, but I was unable to find my answer on any of the associated posts.

I have a small array of three string items. When text is entered into the text box on my form and the "Verify" button is pressed, I should like to verify that the text typed into the text box can in fact be found in the array.

I have been attempting to use the .Contains method, but to no avail. It has only worked for the first item in the array. The others fail to be recognized.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim STRarray as string() = {"RUT","MB","PR"}

if STRarray.contains(textbox.text) Then
    messagebox.show("Item Found.")
else
    messagebox.show("Unable to Locate String.")
end if
```

Now as I stated above, if I type RUT into the textbox, the code works. However if I enter MB or PR it is unable to find them.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try seeing the contents of STRarray?

Comment: Yes I have done that to make sure that my array is in fact populated. Thats why I'm so confused haha.

Answer (score 3):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ks8SFQ ... it is working .. what you are missing

try `Trim` and `ToUpper`.. like below.. it may work

```
Dim STRarray as string() = {"RUT","MB","PR"}

if STRarray.contains(textbox.text.trim().ToUpper()) Then
    messagebox.show("Item Found.")
else
    messagebox.show("Unable to Locate String.")
end if
```

Comment: I'll try this, thank you! I already defaulted all of the text ToUpper through the text box, but I'll give the trim a tr.

Comment: `Trim` and `ToUpper` create unnecessary strings in memory.  Use the overload of `Contains` that allows you to specify a case insensitive comparison:  `STRarray.Contains(textbox.Text, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
`

Comment: whats the different between `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` and `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` ?